# How to add checkbox header column to check all when checked?

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net, webforms

I work on sp.net web forms . I face issue I can't add column checkbox to grid view  as Header column .

so when header column checked then all rows checked on grid view

and when header column not checked then all rows not checked on grid view .

meaning all rows grid view will depend on column header checked or not .

so How to do that using jQuery or java script or CSS .

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewSearchData" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#172b4d" ForeColor="White" OnDataBound="GridViewSearchData_OnDataBound" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" PageSize="1">
            <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSel" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BranchCode" HeaderText="BranchCode" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderNo" HeaderText="OrderNo" ItemStyle-Width="120px" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderType" HeaderText="OrderType" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Printer_name" HeaderText="Printer_name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EntredDatetime" HeaderText="EntredDatetime" />                            
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</div>
```

for grid view data source

```cs
protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt;
    dt = busiObj.DisplayAllSearchData();
               
    if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridViewSearchData.DataSource = dt;
        GridViewSearchData.DataBind();
    }
}
```

image for expected result as red color first column

[image: check all column header check all rows]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First up, how to add "any" control to the header.

It works very much like say any item template.

Start a "item templte", and INSIDE that, drop in a header template.

So, we have this now:

```
<h3>Select Hotels</h3>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" Width="50%" CssClass="table table-hover">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

        <asp:TemplateField
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
            HeaderStyle-Width="70px">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <div style="text-align: center">
                    All<br />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server"
                        OnCheckedChanged="chkAll_CheckedChanged"
                        AutoPostBack="true" />
                </div>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSel" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And we wired up a click event for the check box. So, the code is now this:

```
    protected void chkAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chkHeaderCheck = (CheckBox)sender;
        
        foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox ckRowSel = (CheckBox)gRow.FindControl("chkSel");
            ckRowSel.Checked = chkHeaderCheck.Checked;
        }
    }
```

And now we get/see this:

[image]

So, above is real clean, VERY easy.

of course, we could do this code 100% client side with JavaScript.

So, now out button (header) has no server side click, nor a post-back.

So, this:

```
        <asp:TemplateField
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
            HeaderStyle-Width="70px">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <div style="text-align: center">
                    All<br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHeader" runat="server" 
                            onclick="myheadcheck(this)" />
                </div>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSel" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

And the js code is this: (jQuery)

```
  <script>

      function myheadcheck(btn) {

          // get the ONE check box, checked, or not???
          var bolChecked = $(btn).is(':checked')

          // now set all check boxes
          MyTable = $('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>')    // select and get grid
          MyCheckBoxs = MyTable.find('input:checkbox') // select all check boxes in grid
          MyCheckBoxs.each(function () {
              $(this).prop('checked', bolChecked)
          })
      }
  </script>
```

And now the result is really the same, but no server side post-back.

However, either way? Note the use of the Header template -

And last but not least?

Might as well include the code to load the gv.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadGrid();
        }
    }
    protected void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

example using jquery:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewSearchData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#172b4d" ForeColor="White" OnDataBound="GridViewSearchData_OnDataBound" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" PageSize="1">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select All" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSel" runat="server" CssClass="chkSelectRow" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="BranchCode" HeaderText="BranchCode" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderNo" HeaderText="OrderNo" ItemStyle-Width="120px" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderType" HeaderText="OrderType" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Printer_name" HeaderText="Printer_name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="EntredDatetime" HeaderText="EntredDatetime" />                            
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Add click event to header checkbox
    $(".chkSelectAll").click(function () {
        $(".chkSelectRow").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });

    // Add click event to row checkboxes
    $(".chkSelectRow").click(function () {
        if ($(".chkSelectRow:checked").length == $(".chkSelectRow").length) {
            $(".chkSelectAll").prop('checked', true);
        }
        else {
            $(".chkSelectAll").prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

```
protected void GridViewSearchData_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        CheckBox chkSelectAll = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkSelectAll");
        chkSelectAll.Attributes.Add("onclick", "jQuery('.chkSelectRow').prop('checked', this.checked);");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your missing the markup for the check box chkSelectAll in the header.